# Heop with adding a driver via Terminal

Tags: wireless-access-point

Have a wireless dongle device for which no drivers have been provided for by Ubuntu/Linux.  I can add the driver through the Terminal and make it work.  I have instructions on how to make it a permanent addition to Ubuntu (12.04) but have no clue of how and what to type in to make this driver permanent and to have it available when I start up the program.
My instructions say "to put the module in the list of loaded modules"  "Just add RTL8192cu in /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf"
and  add the following command to /etc/rtc.local: echo ""2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id"
I'm not really up on inputting commands into the terminal program to make things happen.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the terminal is the best way to go - and much faster at that. Just follow the instructions you have and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions above are for some other version of Linux; they are incorrect for Ubuntu. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo rtl8192cu >> /etc/modules
exit
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above 'exit 0' add these two lines:

```
modprobe rtl8192cu
echo "2001 330D" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. You should be all set.